# Dependancies for openCMIS in apache camel

Tags: apache-karaf, cmis, opencmis

Im using openCMIS for storing document in IBM Filenet

Below are my pom entries (openCMIS dependencies)

```
chemistry-opencmis-commons-api
chemistry-opencmis-client-impl
chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl
chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings
chemistry-opencmis-client-api
```

To deploy my osgi bundle in karaf, i installed opencmis by running following commands in karaf

```
install -s wrap:mvn:com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.10
install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.chemistry.opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-commons-api/0.13.0
install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.chemistry.opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl/0.13.0
install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.chemistry.opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-client-api/0.13.0
install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.chemistry.opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings/0.13.0
install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.chemistry.opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-client-impl/0.13.0
```

Now im stuck for these dependencies

```
  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api, 
  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer, 
  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message, 
  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe, 
  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.helper
```

To use openCMIS in my osgi bundle, am i missing any dependency?? or is my jdk the problem is. My jdk is 7.

How to install openCMIS in karaf or how to resolve this `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.*` problem...??

Comment: `com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt` should provide the dependencies you are looking for. what is the error you get ?

Comment: Yes tried installing jaxws-rt. It doesnt contain package like com.sun.xml.internal.ws.*  Couldnt use the chemistry bundles in camel because of this.